# Less Memory Usage

Tags: c++, memory

I have a function which checks if a pattern is inside the provided string. The pattern is predefined and have a lot of them are available 
 eg:

```
  const char* a1 = "apple";
  const char* a2 = "Orange";
  const char* a3 = "mango";
  const char* a4 = "grapes";
  ...
  ...
  ...
  const char* an = "Banana";
```

PS : a1,a2,a3 all are member variables of class FRUIT . And The value assigning is done in constructor. I have the function   :

```
 void FindPattern(sample_String, predefined_string)
  {
     if(strstr(sample_string,predefined_string))
     {
      do sth...
     }
     else
       do another thing

   }
```

so my doubt is it a better approach to create an enum which denotes the predefstrings(a1 to an) and pass them to the function and in a switch case or something assign the "apple" "orange" values locally. Will this approach use less memory than initializing in constructor?

Comment: And the function is incorrectly written: it needs a return type (void, at least), and argument types.

Comment: ok. Edited. I just wrote a sample

Comment: Well, these strings are `const`, so you are copying just a pointer, anyway.

Comment: I can't see the usage of `a1`, `a2`, etc. in function FindPattern. Just finding is `sample_String` contains `predefined_string`... Maybe you call `FindPattern` outside with `an` as the second parameter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand which memory you want to optimize away, here.

Assuming it is the actual members, and their type really is `const char*`, these strings are simply pointers to compile-time constants. These constants will (most likely) be placed inside some constant memory area outside of the stack or heap and only "initialized" by the loading of the program into memory, before any execution begins. Hence, there isn't really any memory usage for you to optimize, since the strings need to be stored *somewhere* in the resulting binaries of your program.

So, the only memory you're actually using for an instance of this class is a single pointer per string. If these pointers will be the same for each instance, you could make them `static`, which more clearly shows the intention. If they really do differ between objects, there is no optimization which can be done. In either case, this is such a small amount of memory that it shouldn't have any impact and you're most likely looking at a premature optimization.

Comment: which is the memory you referred rather than stack and heap

Comment: @ArunC.B That depends on which compiler and OS we're talking about. The memory of a C++ program is split up into a few more segments than the stack and heap. The most likely candidate is the *"Code Segment"*, which is a read-only area where all the executable code is stored. That area is also referred to as "Text", since it often harbours constants such as text strings.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need the string constants either way.

Comment: yes, But I am initializing them in constructor so that around 20 ,30 values are initialized. Is it better or getting them locally(inside the comparestring() function.

Comment: @ArunC.B Are you copying the strings or are you just assigning them? If you're just assigning the strings, no memory is used other than a pointer.

Comment: @ArunC.B No matter where you write a string constant in your source code, it'll end up consuming the required memory (_exactly once_ if you use a reasonable linker). If you additionally introduce an ENUM type, memory consumption is not going to get any better.

Comment: @NikosC. Oh really? And the string value/constant does not require any memory?

Comment: @ClassStacker You're confused. The literals are needed. Copying them isn't. They can remain in one place and only pointers to them can be used.

Comment: @NikosC. I can live with you believing that I'm confused, but I will still say that writing _If you're just assigning the strings, no memory is used other than a pointer_ is not such a good idea when addressing someone who does not have a substantial understanding of what consumes memory and what doesn't. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If all instances share the same set of `a1,a2,...,an` and they are never changed after setting them in the constructor, then it might be a good idea to make them `static` members of `Fruit`, like this:

```
class Fruit {
  static const char* const a1;
  static const char* const a2;
  //...
  static const char* const an;
};

// In Fruit.cpp:
static const char* const Fruit::a1 = "apple";
static const char* const Fruit::a2 = "orange";
//...
static const char* const Fruit::an = "banana";
```

The all instances will share the members `a1,a2,...,an` without any waste of memory.